# How to call a controller method with a button in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 4, is there an elegant way to wrap a link_to around an entire  so that clicking anywhere on the div will call my delete method?

The code I have now simply renders an  inside of my div:

```
div class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><%= link_to "Delete", event_path(event), method: :delete %></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `do` after your `link_to` statement, and then close it afterwards with an `end` tag

```
<%= link_to "Delete", event_path(event), method: :delete do %>
  <div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's what I was missing, the do

Comment: Cool.  You just have to remember if you want a block, just `do` it

Answer (score 1):

Put the block (div) inside your <%= link_to %> tag.  link_to can accept a block.

```
<%= link_to ... %>
<div></div>
<% end %>
```